# Why is my answer wrong in Code jam 2018 "Saving the World Again"?

Tags: python, list, algorithm

The problem is presented here: https://codingcompetitions.withgoogle.com/codejam/round/00000000000000cb/0000000000007966

An alien robot is threatening the universe, using a beam that will destroy all algorithms knowledge. We have to stop it!

Fortunately, we understand how the robot works. It starts off with a beam with a strength of 1, and it will run a program that is a series of instructions, which will be executed one at a time, in left to right order. Each instruction is of one of the following two types:

C (for "charge"): Double the beam's strength.
S (for "shoot"): Shoot the beam, doing damage equal to the beam's current strength.
For example, if the robot's program is SCCSSC, the robot will do the following when the program runs:

Shoot the beam, doing 1 damage.
Charge the beam, doubling the beam's strength to 2.
Charge the beam, doubling the beam's strength to 4.
Shoot the beam, doing 4 damage.
Shoot the beam, doing 4 damage.
Charge the beam, increasing the beam's strength to 8.
In that case, the program would do a total of 9 damage.

The universe's top algorithmists have developed a shield that can withstand a maximum total of D damage. But the robot's current program might do more damage than that when it runs.

The President of the Universe has volunteered to fly into space to hack the robot's program before the robot runs it. The only way the President can hack (without the robot noticing) is by swapping two adjacent instructions. For example, the President could hack the above program once by swapping the third and fourth instructions to make it SCSCSC. This would reduce the total damage to 7. Then, for example, the president could hack the program again to make it SCSSCC, reducing the damage to 5, and so on.

To prevent the robot from getting too suspicious, the President does not want to hack too many times. What is this smallest possible number of hacks which will ensure that the program does no more than D total damage, if it is possible to do so?

Input
The first line of the input gives the number of test cases, T. T test cases follow. Each consists of one line containing an integer D and a string P: the maximum total damage our shield can withstand, and the robot's program.

Output
For each test case, output one line containing Case #x: y, where x is the test case number (starting from 1) and y is either the minimum number of hacks needed to accomplish the goal, or IMPOSSIBLE if it is not possible.

---

I implemented the following logic:
- First calculate the damage of the ship.
- The S has it's greatest value when it is at the end so the swaps should start at end and continue towards the beginning of the list. 
- The C at the end becomes useless so I pop it out of the list so it does not iterate over it again. 
- In order to simplify the O() complexity I decided to subtract the last value of S from theSUM every time a swap is made.
**The test results seem right - but the judge of the system says : Wrong Answer. 
Can you help me find the mistake?**

---

(I know only how to operate with lists and dictionaries in Python 3 and I am an absolute beginner at solving theese questions )
my code is below:

```
for case in range(1,T):
    D, B = input().split()
    D = int(D)
    Blist =[]
    [Blist.append(i) for i in B]

    def beamDamage(Blist):
        theSum=0
        intS=1
        Ccount = 0
        for i in Blist:
            if i == 'S':
                theSum = theSum + intS
            if i == 'C':
                Ccount = Ccount +1
                intS = intS*2
        return theSum

    def swap(Blist):
        temp=''
        for i in range(0,len(Blist)):
            if Blist[len(Blist)- 1] == 'C':
                Blist.pop()
            if (Blist[len(Blist)- i - 1]) == 'C' and (Blist[len(Blist)- i] == 'S'):
                temp = Blist[len(Blist)- i - 1]  # C 
                Blist[len(Blist)- i - 1] = 'S'
                Blist[len(Blist)- i] = temp
                return Blist


    bd = beamDamage(Blist)
    y = 0

    if 'C' not in B:
        if beamDamage(Blist) > D:
            print("Case #{}: IMPOSSIBLE".format(case))
        else:
            print("Case #{}: 0".format(case))
    else:
        while bd > D:  
            swap(Blist)
            pwr=0
            for ch in Blist:
                if ch == 'C':
                    pwr=pwr+1
            bd = bd - 2**(pwr-1)
            y+=1
        print("Case #{}: {}".format(case, y))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will not give you a complete solution, but here is one issue:

If your input is a series of "S" followed by one or more "C" (like "SSSSC"), and the calculated damage is higher than asked for, you'll clearly see that the result is wrong. It should be IMPOSSIBLE...

The reason for the failure is that the condition in `if 'C' not in B:` will not apply, and so the loop will kick in (when it really shouldn't). Consequently `pwr` remains zero and you use a calculation with `2**-1`, which yields a non-integer value.

The solution is to trim the list from terminating `C` characters at the very start, even before doing the `if` test.

Secondly, I don't see the benefit of doing the damage calculation in two different ways. On the one hand you have `beamDamage`, and you also have the inline loop, which does roughly the same (not faster).

Finally, even if you get this right, I suspect your code might run into a timeout, because it is not doing the job efficiently. Think of keeping track of the damage incrementally, without needing to go through the whole list again.

Once you have that improvement, you may still need to tune performance furhter. In that case, think of what damage reduction you would get it you would move a "C" immediately to the very end of the list. If that reduction is still not bringing the damage below the target, you can go for that in one go (but still count the steps correctly).